# Replace semicolon with a break in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, split

I want to break the line wherever semicolon is there.

```js
var locdata = {
        "locations": [{
            "id": 0,
            "name": 'USA',
            "cx": 100,
            "cy": 100,
            "address":'545, 8th ABCDddd, Suite 17SW;New City, NY 10fg018;Tel: 1-21g2-24448-2727/Fax: 1-552-268-7825;Toll Free: 1-866-383-8806;Mr. Johny Pleeto;DirectManager;Mobile no. 1-917-605-0022';

var address = locdata.locations[idvar].address;
  var result = address.replace(/\;/g,'\n');  
            address = result;
 $('div#address').text(address);
```

Comment: it looks ok what do you expect

Answer (score 3):

Simply try

```
split(";").join("\n")
```

```js
var address = '545, 8th ABCDddd, Suite 17SW;New City, NY 10fg018;Tel: 1-21g2-24448-2727/Fax: 1-552-268-7825;Toll Free: 1-866-383-8806;Mr. Johny Pleeto;DirectManager;Mobile no. 1-917-605-0022';
console.log( address.split(";").join("\n") )
```

Comment: Is that meant to be `split(";")`?

Comment: @gcampbell yes, made a typo in a hurry

Answer (score 2):

I think, its a problem of order. You need first to assign the string for replacing, then replace and assign the result.

```js
var address = '545, 8th ABCDddd, Suite 17SW;New City, NY 10fg018;Tel: 1-21g2-24448-2727/Fax: 1-552-268-7825;Toll Free: 1-866-383-8806;Mr. Johny Pleeto;DirectManager;Mobile no. 1-917-605-0022',
    result = address.replace(/\;/g,'\n');

console.log(result);
```

Your code replaces first and then assign the string for replacing. Later you reassign `address` and then you assign a string.

```
var result = address.replace(/\;/g,'\n');  
    address = result;
var address = '545, 8th ABCDddd, Suite 17SW;New City, NY 10fg018;Tel: 1-21g2-24448-2727/Fax: 1-552-268-7825;Toll Free: 1-866-383-8806;Mr. Johny Pleeto;DirectManager;Mobile no. 1-917-605-0022';
```

Answer (score 2):

Given code will work fine in case it is text literal. But If you want to display it in HTML you need to use **`<br/>`** insteed of **\n**

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>

var address = '545, 8th ABCDddd, Suite 17SW;New City, NY 10fg018;Tel: 1-21g2-24448-2727/Fax: 1-552-268-7825;Toll Free: 1-866-383-8806;Mr. Johny Pleeto;DirectManager;Mobile no. 1-917-605-0022';
var result = address.replace(/\;/g,'<br/>');  
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=result;
```

**

> UPDATED:

**

As you updated your question, It helped me to update the answer too..
You need to do 2 changes:

1.

```
address.replace(/\;/g,'<br/>');
```

2.

```
$('div#address').html(address);
```

[CLICK HERE FOR FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/281/)

Comment: Please add some html. How are you displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Just use split(). Try this code

```
var address = '545, 8th ABCDddd, Suite 17SW;New City, NY 10fg018;Tel: 1-21g2-24448-2727/Fax: 1-552-268-7825;Toll Free: 1-866-383-8806;Mr. Johny Pleeto;DirectManager;Mobile no. 1-917-605-0022';
var result = address.split(";");
address = result;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use.

```js
var address = '545, 8th ABCDddd, Suite 17SW;New City, NY 10fg018;Tel: 1-21g2-24448-2727/Fax: 1-552-268-7825;Toll Free: 1-866-383-8806;Mr. Johny Pleeto;DirectManager;Mobile no. 1-917-605-0022';
       var result= address.replace(/\;/g, '\n');
alert(result);
```

Comment: The separator is `;` not `,`

Comment: I think you should escape `;` with `back slash` => `/\;/g`.

Comment: Thanks @mortezaT .

Comment: Try to add code snippets which allow others to see your code result. That would be useful for yourself too.

Comment: Ok @mortezaT,, Thanks. I will do it from next time